# Visual Studio 2017 Could not add the account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Installed 2017 VS Pro, and was unable to login. Came up with this error.

[image: VS Could not add the account]

I've looked around and found only one similar issue which says to remove:

%AppData%Local/.IdentityService Which I've tried a few times.

I had 2015 VS installed as well. No issues with 2015 but thought it might have been having issues with 2017. Removed all 2015 and removed 2017. Re installed 2017. This time opting for Community Version. Again the same issue. I'm trying to connect to TFS, which I can through a web browser with no problems.

[image: Connect to a Project]

Gives me the web login option and I know the username/password is correct.

Any idea what I can do to fix this unknown error?

This error was from trying to login on "B".

---

[image: Login options]

If I try to login from "A" I get this warning.

[image: We could not refresh the credentials for the account]

I get some more information links to troubleshoot with the refresh credentials, but all talk about a token or proxy which isn't the same issue as this one.

On option "A" if I close out the error box, I get this final warning, but again, doesn't search results show me nothing. That would link with this issue.

[image: No longer retrieve information for your account]

Since I can't ever login, I wouldn't expect it to retrieve anything.

---

### Different computer

**This is invalid as R2 (remove and reinstall) showed this.**

Installed the application on a different computer, fairly fresh install. Noticed one major change compared to the computer with the issue.

After install, as soon as I opened the program, it asked for a login right away. I logged in prior to ever getting to the option of "A" or "B". As soon as it loaded, it auto filled my credentials. This points during setup, it pulled local credentials that may or may have not been in place. I'll start by removing local credential and going forward from there.

---

### Credentials

I could not find any TFS credentials in the system. I did however tried to use another account that was never used on this computer, and that too ran into the same issue.

---

Logs from \AppData\Local\Temp\servicehub\logs

```
06/05/2017 15:15:16 : Error : CreateAccount: Creating an account. QueryParameters 'site_id=501454&display=popup&nux=1&lc=1033'
Account creation failed. 
Error: 'Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: unknown_error: Unknown error ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpClientWrapper.<GetResponseAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendHttpMessageAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__56.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.NetworkServicesImpl.<AcquireTokenWithPromptAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.AadAccountProviderService.<CreateAccountAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
    ErrorCode: unknown_error
    StatusCode: 408'
```

Comment: Have you verified you are able ping the TFS server?

Comment: @Ramhound TFS is online and not local. It's working as everyone can login through a web browser.

Comment: See if [this solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/9698/cannot-authenticate-anywhere-in-vs2017rc-sign-in-a.html) applies here.

Comment: @harrymc I've tried the %AppData%Local/.IdentityService already. I saw this posting as well. The second part of this shows some tag outside of the service. Mine has the correct usage, so that's not a fix either.

Comment: This seems to be a [known problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/58033/cannot-add-account-to-vs-2017.html) which Microsoft is still investigating. Try also the other advice in [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/7675/cant-sign-into-accounts.html?childToView=17494).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [known problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/7675/cant-sign-into-accounts.html?childToView=17494) which Microsoft is still investigating. The last message by Microsoft says:

> Sign in to visual studio 2015 in the top right hand corner should
>   work, however File->AccountSettings->Add an account would not work. In
>   vs2017 sign in and add an account would not work. The error seems to
>   indicate some problem between internet explorer which is what is used
>   for the sign in dialog, and something that changed in the last couple
>   of month with the sign in flow using godaddy. I am still investigating
>   what the actual error means in terms of what is failing inside of the
>   browser to see if there is a fix on the visual studio side, or if one
>   needs to be made with the single sign on provider.

This seems to indicate a conflict with the account provider.
It is not clear to me what the conflict is, but you should maybe change
your email provider.

Another [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/7675/cant-sign-into-accounts.html?childToView=17494) relates to accounts
used for Azure, which you can follow if this is your case.

Comment: If VS2015 is working for you, you might possibly stay with it until these sign-in bugs in VS2017 are fixed.